# Proving colinearity of 3 points (Oxford Admissions Test 2 1992)

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

A, B, C are points on a circle S with $AC > BC > AB$.

(i) Suppose that X and Y are two points on S such that
AX=AY=BC.
Show that either

$BX= AC$ and $CY = BA$

or

$BY = AC$ and $CX = BA$.

(ii) If P is a point on S and L, M, N are the feet of the perpendiculars from P to BC,
AC, and AB respectively (sides being extended if necessary), show that L, M, and
N are collinear.

Part (i) can be done by considering when the center of the circle is inside or outside the triangle ABC and then using the circle theorem "Angles subtended by the same arc at the circumference are equal" to prove that some relevant triangles are congruent.

Part (ii) is posing a problem to me, I've found that the initial condition $AC>BC>AB$ is definitely important in the construction.

Also, with the way I've constructed the triangle and chosen the position of P, you can see that M is the intersection of lines LN and AC. By drawing a line parallel to AC and passing through N you can quickly prove that L,N and this intersection must be collinear. However, I can't seem to prove that this intersection must be M. Since we aren't assuming that this intersection point is M, we can't assume that the angle is 90.

I know that it's very possible that I'm considering the completely wrong approach so if someone could help me with either proving that the intersection is M or some other method, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, we join $ML$, $LN$, $BP$ and $CP$ as shown.

Going to show that $M, L, N$ are collinear by showing that $\angle MLP + \angle PLN= 180^o$

This can be done by observing that $PLBM$, $PBAC$ and $PCNL$ are cyclic quadrilaterals.

Hence $\angle PLM =\angle PBM = \angle PCN $

Also $\angle PCN + \angle PLN = 180^o $

Hence $\angle MLP + \angle PLN= 180^o$

and $M, L, N$ are collinear.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like I don't have that much experience with cyclic quadrilaterals. I've been stuck on this problem for so long.

Comment: You are welcome.